# mysql connect fails with CA specified

Tags: mysql, ssl

I used to run a service, which accesses mysql by certificate and key, but without password. Now my root cert was expired, which put me into deep trouble. However, this is what is running:

```
mysql --ssl --ssl-verify-server-cert --ssl-cert mlist.cert.pem --ssl-key mlist.key.pem --host mysql.example.com -u mlist -- MList
```

But things go awry, when I specify the CA:

```
mysql --ssl --ssl-verify-server-cert --ssl-ca cacert.pem  --ssl-cert mlist.cert.pem --ssl-key mlist.key.pem --host mysql.example.com -u mlist -- MList 
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error
```

However, `openssl verify -CAfile cacert.pem somecert.pem` returns `OK` for `mlist.cert.pem` and in particular also for `mysql.cert.pem` set as server certificate option `ssl-cert` in `my.cnf`. Given the wireshark trace apparently that certificate is actually sent by the mysql server.

The mysql client is a bit old: 5.0.51a. mysql server is 5.5.44. The new CA has a slightly different subject, i.e. a latin1 encoded character is now encoded utf8.

Is there any method for systematic debugging?

Comment: "The new CA has a slightly different subject, i.e. a latin1 encoded character is now encoded utf8." -- that's probably going to be a problem.

Comment: Could you please be a little clearer why? Of course the new certificates are signed by the new root and have "X509v3 Authority Key Identifier" set correctly. The new CA has the string encoded as UTF8STRING. The old one had T61STRING encoded as latin1. So it looks all quite sane.